# How can one manually assign papers to program committee members in easychair?

Tags: easychair

I read that the way to do it is going to the assignment tab:

[image]

However, I don't see any assignment tab on my side even when connected as the track chair or superchair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, one cannot manually assign papers to program committee members in easychair. It has to be enable as follows (log in as the superchair):

EasyChair Menu > Administration > Configure > “Paper bidding and assignment” section ->  Is viewing bids of PC members by chairs enabled? -> set to ‘yes’.

[image]